# Login system with Django, Kivy and SHA256

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework, kivy

I've created a simple REST API to list and create users with Django REST Framework and I'm trying to integrate it with an Kivy app. I've used the `django.contrib.auth.models.User` as my user class, and passwords are being created as show below:

*serializers.py*

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import serializers


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = super(UserSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()
        return user
```

As I'm using the `set_password` function, my REST API gives me SHA256 hashed passwords when I list my users:

```
GET /list/
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

[
    {
        "username": "user1",
        "first_name": "Katy",
        "last_name": "Smith",
        "email": "katysmith@domain.com",
        "password": "pbkdf2_sha256$216000$rV8FoNw98RYu$0pdfnA4HO+15o4ov4GZVMXiq0tLNJopfLDV++iPvC5E="
    },
    {
        "username": "user2",
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Smith",
        "email": "johnsmith@domain.com",
        "password": "pbkdf2_sha256$216000$q4wfz8tiFnnF$gmOuN7HJurbEqHykZ221UX8STcG9pAQ8WQTKF+qDtbw="
    },
```

With that backend, I'm creating an app frontend with Kivy. I have a login screen that asks users to input their username and password. My thinking about how should I create a login system (as I'm just a student in programming) is:

1. Use `urllib.request` to get the user list;
2. Loop and check if the username provided is in the list;
3. Check if the password provided is the password store for that user in that list.

Concerning the logic of this operation, if passwords were stored in plain text, I could simple compare string with the password given by the user. But as they're hashed... how can I do it? How can I check if this hashed password 'match' with the one provided by the user on the login screen?

Also, I would consider a bonus if you can answer this: my login "strategy" is correct? There's a better way to create a login system using this tools I have? If so, how?

Comment: I think this is what you need,
https://dev.to/nobleobioma/adding-authentication-to-a-rest-framework-django-api-1e5a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a web service that you are using to handle login info then it should be the only one that does hashing and authenticating.

You should NEVER send a list of users and their hashed passwords to the client and then have the client authenticate there password against that list. This is a huge security issue.

Here's how a username and password authentication system works.

1. Client sends their username and un-hashed password to the server via https to a certain endpoint. eg. mywebsite.com/login
2. The server receives this request and and retrieves a user with that username if it exists from the database.
3. You then grab the hashed password for that user from the database as well and you then hash the password sent via https request the same way. And compare the two to see if they match.
4. If they match you need to send back an api key/authentication token to the client that they will use for all future requests. That api key/authentication token should be stored in the server's database to later be retrieved for requests.
5. From now on the client sends that api key/authentication token to the server for any requests it needs and the server checks to make sure the key/token is valid and then ignores or processes the request further.

This is a simplified version of the whole process cause there is also salt and peppering a password before hashing. There is expiration times that need to be added to key/tokens so that they dont last forever and other things.

Google around for how authentication systems work and the proper workflow for an authentication system. Hope this helps and @CyberSrikanth referenced a good article to use for getting started.